# Unable to run Geth in dev mode

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm having trouble running Geth in developer mode. I'm following the instructions from https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started/dev-mode however this returns an error that the chaindata directory is missing.

```
~ > mkdir -p playground/data

~ > cd playground/

~/playground > geth version
Geth
Version: 1.10.2-stable
Git Commit: 97d11b0187b4695ccf44e3b71b54155fe405a36f
Git Commit Date: 20210408
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.16.3
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/home/seth/.go
GOROOT=go

~/playground > geth --datadir data --http --dev --http.corsdomain "https://remix.ethereum.org,http://remix.ethereum.org"
INFO [05-09|12:59:15.378] Starting Geth in ephemeral dev mode... 
INFO [05-09|12:59:15.379] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [05-09|12:59:15.379] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [05-09|12:59:15.385] Set global gas cap                       cap=25000000
INFO [05-09|12:59:16.815] Using developer account                  address=0xd5f1D8F768BC84b1B52380f11e66663E5d7CdF02
INFO [05-09|12:59:16.815] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/seth/playground/data/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=262144 readonly=true
Fatal: Could not open database: stat /home/seth/playground/data/geth/chaindata: no such file or directory
```

If I use Puppeth to create a genesis JSON file and run `geth init sethnet.json` I do get a chaindata directory created and am able to start the dev server.

```
~ > mkdir -p playground/data

~ > cd playground/

~/playground > cp ~/sethnet.json ./

~/playground > geth --datadir data init sethnet.json 
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.353] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.353] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.354] Set global gas cap                       cap=25000000
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.354] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/seth/playground/data/geth/chaindata cache=16.00MiB handles=16
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.374] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.377] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=354 size=50.23KiB time="727.404?s" gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.377] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata hash="e4d24b?603449"
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.377] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/seth/playground/data/geth/lightchaindata cache=16.00MiB handles=16
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.391] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.394] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=354 size=50.23KiB time="684.181?s" gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [05-09|13:24:58.394] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata hash="e4d24b?603449"

~/playground > geth --datadir data --http --dev
INFO [05-09|13:25:09.593] Starting Geth in ephemeral dev mode... 
INFO [05-09|13:25:09.594] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [05-09|13:25:09.594] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [05-09|13:25:09.594] Set global gas cap                       cap=25000000
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.022] Using developer account                  address=0xc3b9eE0Ad804D312CDd63745Cb74A81Df08EA4Ef
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.022] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/seth/playground/data/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=262144 readonly=true
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.053] Opened ancient database                  database=/home/seth/playground/data/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=true
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.053] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.053] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/seth/playground/data/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=262144
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Opened ancient database                  database=/home/seth/playground/data/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 25335 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 Petersburg: 0 Istanbul: 0, Muir Glacier: <nil>, Berlin: <nil>, YOLO v3: <nil>, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/seth/playground/data/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/seth/.ethash                     count=2
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=1337 dbversion=<nil>
WARN [05-09|13:25:11.082] Upgrade blockchain database version      from=<nil> to=8
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash="e4d24b?603449" td=524288 age=18m38s
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash="e4d24b?603449" td=524288 age=18m38s
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash="e4d24b?603449" td=524288 age=18m38s
WARN [05-09|13:25:11.082] Failed to load snapshot, regenerating    err="missing or corrupted snapshot"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.082] Rebuilding state snapshot 
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.083] Deleted state snapshot leftovers         kind=accounts wiped=0 elapsed="23.649?s"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.083] Deleted state snapshot leftovers         kind=storage  wiped=0 elapsed="24.688?s"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.083] Compacting snapshot account area  
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.083] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.083] Wiper running, state snapshotting paused accounts=0 slots=0 storage=0.00B elapsed="160.871?s"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.091] Compacting snapshot storage area  
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.091] Compacted snapshot area in database      elapsed=8.380ms
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.091] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="b84523?07823f" accounts=0 slots=0 storage=0.00B elapsed="4.206?s"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.094] Generated state snapshot                 accounts=256 slots=0 storage=9.50KiB elapsed=2.582ms
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.149] Allocated fast sync bloom                size=512.00MiB
WARN [05-09|13:25:11.149] Error reading unclean shutdown markers   error="leveldb: not found"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.149] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.2-stable-97d11b01/linux-amd64/go1.16.3
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.149] Initialized state bloom                  items=354 errorrate=0.000 elapsed="489.101?s"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.163] New local node record                    seq=1 id=42ff46e0372187a8 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=0 tcp=41407
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.164] Started P2P networking                   self="enode://f16be45336b99494f2c45998e01d1fad62771f19284e216e959e3a87ad56240f71c7bd15b2a504efb5205c439501a6d440e89b671680afd1232fe2a8e111a90f@127.0.0.1:41407?discport=0"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.164] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/home/seth/playground/data/geth.ipc
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.164] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 prefix= cors= vhosts=localhost
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.164] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1000000000
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.164] Updated mining threads                   threads=0
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.164] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.164] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0xc3b9eE0Ad804D312CDd63745Cb74A81Df08EA4Ef
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.164] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash="2cda1a?b5bf30" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="77.352?s"
INFO [05-09|13:25:11.171] Mapped network port                      proto=tcp extport=41407 intport=41407 interface=NAT-PMP(192.168.2.1)
```

More promising however when I continue with the instructions, I'm unable to transfer ether to my new test account.

```
~/playground > geth attach data/geth.ipc 
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.10.2-stable-97d11b01/linux-amd64/go1.16.3
coinbase: 0xc3b9ee0ad804d312cdd63745cb74a81df08ea4ef
at block: 0 (Sun May 09 2021 13:06:33 GMT-0500 (CDT))
 datadir: /home/seth/playground/data
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 ethash:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

To exit, press ctrl-d

> personal.newAccount()
Passphrase: 
Repeat passphrase: 
"0xdb14654ca01515df4bc8a2212959331a7a555b63"

> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether")})
Error: insufficient funds for transfer
    at web3.js:6347:37(47)
    at web3.js:5081:62(37)
    at <eval>:1:20(19)

>  eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
0
>
```

All I'm looking to do is setup a local, developer setup so I can play around without worrying about external networks. All of the tutorials I've looked at so far have been dead ends.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles across this question: In `genesis.json`, you have to list the accounts (`0xdb14654ca01515df4bc8a2212959331a7a555b63`) with their initial balances; otherwise their balance is zero and the only way to get Ether is by mining it. When you use `puppeth`, you will be asked for accounts and their initial balances